# I am having application error when I launched my app from heroku , from the logs I found out it that it is the Procfile

Tags: python, django, heroku, procfile

As I said above the Procfile is the problem
Project name is Purchase_Site
This is my Profile :

```
web: gunicorn Purchase_Site.wsgi --log-file -
```

The log says :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Purchase_Site'
```

The whole log :

```
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279255+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279366+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279390+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279537+00:00 app[web.1]: super().run()
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279549+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279657+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279669+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 229, in run
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279932+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2021-09-14T18:45:52.279947+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 342, in halt
2021-09-14T18:45:52.280193+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2021-09-14T18:45:52.280207+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2021-09-14T18:45:52.281978+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2021-09-14T18:45:52.281995+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 242, in handle_chld
2021-09-14T18:45:52.282177+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2021-09-14T18:45:52.282191+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2021-09-14T18:45:52.282412+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2021-09-14T18:45:52.282485+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2021-09-14T18:45:52.424348+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-09-14T18:45:52.471038+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-14T18:45:57.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-09-14T18:46:08.354861+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=site-buy.herokuapp.com request_id=49f86d09-f07f-41f3-8eaf-2c73ebeb3bb6 fw
d="116.68.86.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-09-14T19:00:04.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user heygivemeahifi@gmail.com
2021-09-14T19:00:34.340351+00:00 app[api]: Release v17 created by user heygivemeahifi@gmail.com
2021-09-14T19:00:34.340351+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 17d90df9 by user heygivemeahifi@gmail.com
2021-09-14T19:00:34.577324+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-14T19:00:37.944587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Purchase_Site.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-09-14T19:00:38.914964+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-09-14T19:00:38.917020+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:40439 (4)
2021-09-14T19:00:38.917078+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-09-14T19:00:38.920938+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925233+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925234+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925234+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925235+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925235+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925235+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925235+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925236+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925236+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925236+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925236+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925237+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925237+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925237+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925237+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925238+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925238+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925238+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925239+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925239+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Purchase_Site'
2021-09-14T19:00:38.925342+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-09-14T19:00:38.959320+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-09-14T19:00:38.959426+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:38 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-09-14T19:00:39.103320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-09-14T19:00:39.269514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-14T19:00:39.281176+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-09-14T19:00:43.457284+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn Purchase_Site.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-09-14T19:00:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-09-14T19:00:45.009786+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2021-09-14T19:00:45.011407+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:29775 (4)
2021-09-14T19:00:45.011467+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-09-14T19:00:45.014855+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018699+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018701+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018701+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018702+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018702+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018702+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018703+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018703+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018703+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018704+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018704+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018704+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018705+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018705+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018705+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018706+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018706+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 972, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018707+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018708+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018708+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018708+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Purchase_Site'
2021-09-14T19:00:45.018815+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2021-09-14T19:00:45.056489+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-09-14T19:00:45.057191+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-09-14 19:00:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-09-14T19:00:45.259769+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-09-14T19:00:45.377262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-09-14T19:00:50.473167+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=site-buy.herokuapp.com request_id=4b4fc117-9f3e-4843-b874-f2db0e460302 fw
d="116.68.86.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

The rest of the project code is here :
https://github.com/Shadow-Knight503/Site_Buy

Comment: Whatever I observed , your wsgi must be web.wsgi.application

see on settings:
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'web.wsgi.application'

Comment: I checked it out WSGI_APPLICATION was 'web.wsgi.application' . Whenever i change the project name in Procfile l get Module not found <the name i gave > Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: That GitHub link doesn't load. This is likely a private project.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us your directory structure.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.